# On the initialization of std::array

Tags: c++, c++11, tr1

Let's say you have a c++0x std::array member of a template class and you want to initialize it by means of a constructor that takes a couple of iterators:

```
template <typename Tp, size_t N>
class Test 
{
public:
    template <typename Iterator>
    Test(Iterator first, Iterator last)
    {
        if (std::distance(first,last) > N )
            throw std::runtime_error("bad range");
        std::copy(first, last, _M_storage.begin());
    }

private:
    std::array<Tp, N> _M_storage;

};
```

Assuming that you are providing a range congruent with the size of your storage, is it possible to initialize the std::array in the constructor initializer, avoiding the superflous default constructors of Tps in the storage? Is it possible to exploit the std::initializer_list<> in this case?

Comment: By the way, an identifier that starts with an underscore and is followed by a capital letter is reserved. Also, it should be `std::distance(first, last)`.

Comment: Oversight fixed. The problem with the extra default constructors remains...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

`std::array` is an aggregate, so you get no special functionality like constructors taking iterators. (This actually surprises me, with the introduction of `std::initializer_list` I see no harm in making other useful constructors. Perhaps a question is in store.)

This means the only way to use iterators to copy data inside the array is to iterate, and to do that the `array` must be already constructed and ready to use.